# Banding in waveform monitor

Tags: premiere, color-grading

What does it mean if my Lumetri Scopes in Premiere Pro look like this? [image]

There is some kind of "banding" in it. Does it happen when you color grade 8-bit footage?

Answer (score 1):

The "banding" you are seeing is the levels of the [three channels](https://wolfcrow.com/blog/understanding-luminance-and-chrominance/) that make up a video signal. It isn't an 8-bit artifact. In the upper left and bottom scopes, the white/grey trace is the luminance channel and the others are the color difference channels. In the histogram in the upper right, you are seeing the white and RGB values.

You can [switch between different scope configurations](https://larryjordan.com/articles/premiere-pro-cc-the-new-lumetri-video-scopes/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I was talking about the banding (which looks like some values are missing) found in the waveform.  You can see a picture here: https://ibb.co/mttevR

Comment: Can you share the video frame that corresponds to that waveform?

Comment: @Bob Including a copy of the original frame where this was taken is invaluable for determining if banding is an issue. What kind of video are you working with? Is it footage recorded on a camcorder or a composition of digital created elements (lower thirds, title screens, infographics, etc...)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the originale frame anymore but I can post something similar.  https://imgur.com/a/fQzye https://imgur.com/a/W3BFi